# How to delete two security groups referenced by each other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I was trying to connect to an RDS Instance from an EC2 instance. This resulted in creation of security groups for both of these resources. Now I do not want this connection and have deleted the RDS instance but the security groups still exist. How can I delete them?

When I try to delete them from console it says:

```
The following security groups can't be deleted. They are either default security groups, referenced by other security groups, or they are associated with instances or network interfaces.
Reason: 1 security group associated
```

These security groups were also attached to network interfaces earlier which was also a reason for why I couldn't delete them but I was able to disassociate them from these security groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the particular rule referencing the other security group (or edit to something else) first. This removes the dependency and you'll be able to delete the security group itself.